# What is a SSMS analogue for Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

What is (if there is) the analogue of SQL Server Management Studio for Oracle databases?

Question seems easy but Google didn't know a thing.

I've never worked with Oracle database, now I will have my first encounter soon so I'd like to be a little prepared.

Comment: look into Toad (not free but widely used) or SQL Developer (free from Oracle).

Comment: I'd have guessed that you're looking for SQL Developer, but for any question like this, it's worth mentioning what specific feature(s) you're looking for - it's always possible that the way functionality has been divided and packaged into tools for one system don't match the way functionality has been divided up on a different one - so you may be looking for multiple actual tools.

Comment: @tbone there are free versions of [toad](http://toadworld.com/Downloads/tabid/841/Default.aspx)

Comment: @tschmit007 good to know, I've been using Toad for many years, but at work where we want and use the full pay version.  Not sure whats included/excluded with the freebie version (my guess this came about due to SQL Developer gaining popularity).

Comment: @tbone I fully agree. less than 1 year toad was not free at all.

Answer (score 4):

It depends.  There are a number of applications that could be used depending on what specifically you are trying to do.

If you are trying to administer the database, you would probably want to use Enterprise Manager.  This is a web-based application that lets you monitor and administer the database.  It can either be configured to run just on a particular database server (Enterprise Manager Database Control) or it can be configured to allow you to access all the databases and a variety of non-database products running in the organization (Enterprise Manager Grid Control).  Grid Control is, obviously, a much more involved install.  The Database Control should be installed when you install the database (though some DBAs will turn it off because they don't want to run a HTTP server on their database server).

If you are trying to write and debug PL/SQL code (packages, procedures, functions, triggers, etc.) or to just run some ad-hoc SQL statements, Oracle provides a free tool [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) that can be used.  There are a variety of other PL/SQL IDEs out there as well-- [Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-oracle/) from Quest and [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) from AllAroundAutomations are two of the more common ones.

Oracle also has a basic command-line SQL tool [SQL*Plus](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/toc.htm) that will exist pretty much wherever you are (in much the same way that `vi` will be available on just about any Unix machine you log in to).  There are lots of DBAs (and a decent number of developers) that prefer to use SQL*Plus rather than using the various GUIs.  At a minimum, in most large organizations, DBAs will use SQL*Plus to execute scripts built by the developers as part of the code promotion process so you'll want to have a basic familiarity with SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Oracle [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) which is free from oracle.

[Toad](http://toadworld.com/) is also available.

Comment: Toad is available for free... but in a single product version: one toad express for oracle, one toad express for sql server...